# How to extract text from wikipedia using Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, wiki

I want to extract the whole wikipedia article using jsoup. There are many examples but that's not what I'm looking for. By extracting whole wikipedia article I understand text, tables, etc. Could you give me some examples?

Comment: URL url = new URL(link to wikipedia's article);
Document d = Jsoup.parse(url, 5000);
System.out.println(d.toString());
It gives me html document and not the whole text (I mean some links to other pages)

Comment: Maybe it will be better if i use jwpl or Bliki engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for information. After a hour I've dealt with this problem.

```
    String url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements paragraphs = doc.select(".mw-content-ltr p, .mw-content-ltr li");

    Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
    Element lastParagraph = paragraphs.last();
    Element p;
    int i = 1;
    p = firstParagraph;
    System.out.println(p.text());
    while (p != lastParagraph) {
        p = paragraphs.get(i);
        System.out.println(p.text());
        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dawn.com"+"/")
      .userAgent("Mozilla")   
      .timeout(3000)
      .get();
    //start
    Elements paragraphs = doc.select(".mw-content-ltr p, .mw-content-ltr li");
       Element firstParagraph = paragraphs.first();
       Element lastParagraph = paragraphs.last();
       Element p;
       int i = 1;
       p = firstParagraph;
       System.out.println("testing");
       if(paragraphs.hasText())
       {
        System.out.println("it is not empty");
       }
       else
       {
        System.out.println("is empty");
       }

Comment: I am unabe to edit my comment so that it could be indented .  please help me put here . 
Also this code i posted is printing "is empty" ,which means that the 3rd line in your code is somehow not working . I am trying to get only the text content from the link in my program .

Comment: Awesome, +1 and Thanks. For future readers the select in doc.select works exactly as https://api.jquery.com/select/

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Rest API for extract the data

[http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API%3aMain_page)